# CONCAT equivalent in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm doing some work in MS Access and I need to append a prefix to a bunch of fields, I know SQL but it doesn't quite seem to work the same in Access

Basically I need this translated to a command that will work in access:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET [My Column] = CONCAT ("Prefix ", [My Column]) 
WHERE [Different Column]='someValue';
```

I've searched up and down and can't seem to find a simple translation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET [My Column] = "Prefix " & [My Column] 
WHERE [Different Column]='someValue';
```

As far as I am aware there is no CONCAT

Comment: Thanks Fred, worked perfectly.  It's weird that ACCESS doesn't allow all SQL functions.

Answer (score 18):

There are two concatenation operators available in Access: `+`; and `&`.  They differ in how they deal with Null.

`"foo" + Null` returns Null

`"foo" & Null` returns `"foo"`

So if you want to update Null `[My Column]` fields to contain `"Prefix "` afterwards, use ...

```sql
SET [My Column] = "Prefix " & [My Column]
```

But if you prefer to leave it as Null, you could use the `+` operator instead ...

```sql
SET [My Column] = "Prefix " + [My Column]
```

However, in the second case, you could revise the `WHERE` clause to ignore rows where `[My Column]` contains Null.

```sql
WHERE [Different Column]='someValue' AND [My Column] Is Not Null
```

Comment: Ah, I had not realized there was a difference in the two, thanks HansUp, this is good to know as I do not want to Null out all my values!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `&` operator:

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET [My Column] = "Prefix " & [My Column]
    WHERE [Different Column]='someValue';
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no Concat function in MS-ACCESS, you can simply combine both strings with `+` operator:

```
  UPDATE myTable
 SET [My Column] = "Prefix " + [My Column]
 WHERE [Different Column]='someValue';
```

Comment: For string concatination you should use & as it explicitly a string operation.  The plus sign could give unexpected results