# Group multiple entries in semicolon separated column

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, left-join

I'm creating a left join on two tables and as expected I'm getting multiple entries because the second table might have multiple entries for the unique number in the first column. Instead of having multiple entries I'd like to have one entry and insert all the values that cause them to be multiple into a semicolon separated column.

What i get just now

```
Record No | Record Title | Tag No |
1000      | Document     | A-100  |
1000      | Document     | B-100  |
```

what I'd like to achieve

```
Record No | Record Title | Tag No
1000      | Document     | A-100; B-100
```

Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT *
FROM [EDMS_ADOC_MAS] as a
LEFT JOIN [DOCUMENT_TAGS] as b ON a.[DOC_NUMBER] = b.[DOC_NUMBER]
WHERE a.LOCN_CD Like "*MDP6*"
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using (product specific functionality may be handy here.) And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Apologies, I'm using Access

Comment: you need to concatenate the columns, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403870/concat-equivalent-in-ms-access OR this : https://theaccessbuddy.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/2-handy-concatenation-operators-in-ms-access-operator-types-4-of-5/

Comment: Thanks for all the help and pointing me in the right direction. In case anyone stumbles across this post I found my solution for this using the VBA code found in the below link. A very easy to use and useful function.   Here's the stack overflow question that gave a good example of how to use the function [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value) and here's the vba function
[link](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)