# Undefined function 'Concat' in expression. for Bartender SQL Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, bartender

I'm currently setting up a label on Bartender. Currently I'm on Database setup screen and already have connected an excel sheet to it.

Inside an excel sheet, I have a column that is prefixed with a barcode number starting digits are `'5011'`. Inside an excel sheet I can select few records and drag down to generate more barcodes. e.g. if you have numbers going down a cell `1,2,3...` and you select all three and drag down you have numbers following up with`4,5,6,7,8` etc... same principle with my barcodes.

But.. the `'5011'` needs to start with a `'0'`, so it becomes `'05011'`. If I format my barcodes with an `'0'` and drag down, cells do not update to what they should to. e.g. `01,02,03..` will continue like this: `03,03,03,03,03` repetitively.. even when refreshing the workbook with `F9`

I need an SQL query that just simply adds an extra `'0'` at the start for the barcode column and shows all results within the sheet.

I have managed to use this query to run on excel sheet:

```
`SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];
```

just not sure how to add that extra `0` for column named `Outer Barcodes`

and have tried this:

```
UPDATE `Sheet1$` SET `Outer Barcode` = Concat('0',`Outer Barcode`)
```

but an error message comes up with:
Undefined function 'Concat' in expression.

Comment: What is the underlying DBMS product you are using?

Comment: I have spoken to a support team on Bartender, I have followed their instuctions and given me this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255  I believe this should say which DBMS product im using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CONCAT equivalent in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403870/concat-equivalent-in-ms-access)

Comment: As mentioned in that other question, try ... `SET [Outer Barcode] = '0' & [Outer Barcode]`

Comment: Error: Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'. this is what it comes up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `concat()` operator in MS Access is `&`:

```
UPDATE [Sheet1$]
    SET [Outer Barcode] = '0' & [Outer Barcode];
```

Comment: Hi Gordon! this is the error message:Error: Operation must use an updateable query.

Comment: select '0' & [Outer Barcode] from [Sheet1$] this is what I have used. Its working now. Thanks for the MS Access operator, helped me alot!